# Using a Arduino Pro Mini to power more than 2 servos

Tags: arduino, programming, servo

I don't know very much about Arduino, but from some basic research I have read that the Arduino Pro Mini can only support two servo motors.

I am trying to create a set of [reaction wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel) using hard drives, brushless motor controllers and an Arduino Pro Mini. (I can get a different model of Arduino, but that's what I had lying around.)

Since a set of reaction wheels requires a minimum of three hard drives to work, I need to find a way to be able to control another servo using my Mini.

***Is it possible to control more than two servos (with precision) when using an Arduino Pro Mini?***

If so, how?

If not, should I look into a different model of Arduino? Since I value small size, will an Arduino Micro work?

Comment: Where did you read that Arduino Pro Mini can only support two servo motors?  Could you add a link, please?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't remember. I can go through my search history and try to find it if it helps. If that's not true, then how many can it support?

Comment: @NickAlexeev *How many can it support without added shields or breadboards?

Comment: @NickAlexeev older versions of the Servo library for Arduino only worked on pins 9 and 10 (iirc). Newer versions have removed that restriction. The Pro Mini has 6 PWM pins, and should be able to handle that many servos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct. There was a limit in early versions of the Servo library, but that's been removed. The Pro Mini uses the same ATMega 328p chip as a full-size arduino, so the only limitation is the number of PWM pins that are broken out. There are [6 on a Pro Mini](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini), and the library supports [up to 12](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/servo) on a non-mega.

Also - note that the [arduino micro is based on the ATmega32u4 chip](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMicro), which means it'll behave like a Leonardo, not a standard Uno. It has 7 PWM pins.